# Import confusing by Pycharm inspection

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, pycharm

I develop API on Windows10(Python3.7) for Ubuntu 18.04.2(python3.5). At one moment i moved my project files into subfolder:

```
project_folder/
    sub/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        main.py
```

**app.py**

```
def create_app():
    return 'app'
```

**main.py**

```
from sub.app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

On Windows import was success, but on ubuntu i get import problem. In sys.path() a have first path like `full_path_to_project/project_folder/sub`, but still have error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'`. I moved main.py to start project from `project_folder/sub` into `project_folder` and it was resolve import error.

When i returned to this issue, i suddenly discovered that if i will import like `from app import create_app` against `from sub.app import create_app`, i can move `main.py` into `sub` folder without import error, but Pycharm inspection highlight it as error `Unresoled references`.

[image]

I was confused by the PyCharm alerts on my import. New import works at both Windows and Ubuntu. Did i do something wrong or it is PyCharm problem? And why i cant do `from sub.app import create app` when i have `full_path_to_project/project_folder/sub` in my `sys.path`?

Comment: Mark `sub` as a Source Root by right-clicking on the folder in the project tree and selecting "Mark Directory as ...". This way PyCharm will understand `foo` should be in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @PavelKarateev Worked for me. You should make this an answer.